# NTLM authentication in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In What's new in Silverlight 4 page at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772166(v=VS.95).aspx#networking
under section: Client HTTP Processing >> "Basic and NTLM authentication support" is mentioned as a feature. Could someone explain this particular feature in more detail? A piece of sample code demonstrating "NTLM authentication" in Silverlight App would be ideal.

On above mentioned what's new page there is a link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(v=VS.95).aspx but it was not of much help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MSDN Documentation for this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744835%28VS.95%29.aspx).